# jQuery code doesn't work in an ".aspx" page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've added in an **".aspx" page some JS code based on jQuery**, but **it doesn't work**. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('Hello');
        });
    </script>
```

It is under a  tag without *"runat=server"* attribute and I don't know the origin of the problem because **the JS consoles of the webbrowser doesn't register any error**.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<script>` tag should not be self-closing. So:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js" />
```

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
```

Also make sure that `jquery-1.6.4.js` exists on the specified url.

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery script tag is self-closed, which is illegal HTML.

Change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

the usual form to do this could be the following:

```
<html>                                                                  
 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>          

 <script type="text/javascript">              

   $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('Hello');
        });

 </script>

 </head>
...
```

if your file `jquery-1.6.4.js` is in a subfolder you should properly point to it in the inclusion script.